# Recyclerview with Tablelayout On row click listner not working in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code I was implemented recyclerview with tablelayout .when On click of the table row I have written my code.But below this is showing an error

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

patientListAdapter = new PatientListAdapter(requireContext(),getRegisterdPatientList,this);
recycler_view.setAdapter(patientListAdapter);//error at this

java:
popup:

```
public class DateTimeCoordinator extends Fragment implements PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.SelectItemClickListner {

     patient_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_patientlist,null);
                    recycler_view=customView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                    search=customView.findViewById(R.id.search);
                    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            true);
                    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
                    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
                            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(customView, Gravity.CENTER ,0, 0);
                    popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    getRegisteredPatientListpopup();
                    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                    getRegisterdPatientList = new ArrayList<>();
                    patientListAdapter = new PatientListCoordinatorAdapter(requireContext(), getRegisterdPatientList,get);
                    recycler_view.setAdapter(patientListAdapter);
    
                    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            patientListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

@Override
public void mySelectItemListner(int i) {

```
}
```

Adapter.java:

```
public class PatientListCoordinatorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData> getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList;
    private ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData> mFilteredList;
    private PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.SelectItemClickListner selectItemClickListner;
    public PatientListCoordinatorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData> getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList,PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.SelectItemClickListner selectItemClickListner){
        this.context=context;
        this.getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList=getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList;
        mFilteredList=getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList;
        this.selectItemClickListner=selectItemClickListner;
    }



    @Override
    public PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_patientlist, parent, false);
        PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PatientListCoordinatorAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int i) {



        if(mFilteredList!=null &&mFilteredList.size()>0){
            GetRegisterdPatientListData model=mFilteredList.get(i);
            holder.name.setText(model.getFName()+" "+model.getLName());
            holder.reg_no.setText(model.getRegistrationNo());
            holder.mobile_no.setText(model.getMobile());


                    selectItemClickListner.mySelectItemListner(i);



        }else {
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (GetRegisterdPatientListData androidVersion : getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList) {

                        if (androidVersion.getFName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)||androidVersion.getLName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)||androidVersion.getRegistrationNo().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                                ||androidVersion.getMobile().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                            filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name,reg_no,mobile_no,book_appointment;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            book_appointment=itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_appointment);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            reg_no=itemView.findViewById(R.id.reg_no);
            mobile_no=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_num);
        }

    }
    public interface SelectItemClickListner{
        void mySelectItemListner(int i);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should post this error...

Comment: @snachmsm change the 3rd paramter of the method PatientListAdapter from SelectIemClickListner to OnClickListner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Activity` or `Fragment` (which holds `RecyclerView` and adapter) isn't implementing `PatientListAdapter.SelectIemClickListner`, instead there is an `View.OnClickListener` implementation. you should add `SelectIemClickListner` after coma, implement needed method (`mySelectIemListner(int i)`) and then try to build an app

some sample how it should look for and `Activity`

```
class CustomActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
    View.OnClickListener, PatientListAdapter.SelectIemClickListner {

    override fun mySelectIemListner(i: Integer) {
        // on item click implementation
    }

    // rest of code
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: update your code in question, post whole class

Comment: When I am using inside the popup this is showing an error .outside the popup no error

Comment: `this` is pointing on outer class, e.g. used in some method in `Activity` points on `Activity`.  your interface is implemented by `Fragment` so `this` should refer to it, but as it is placed inside `View.OnClickListener` - it points on it, not on `Fragment`. use `DateTimeCoordinator.this` (Java) / `this@DateTimeCoordinator` (Kotlin) for pointing on proper object ("outer outer"). sample: `new PatientListCoordinatorAdapter(requireContext(), getRegisterdPatientList, DateTimeCoordinator.this)`